# Image not being displayed in browser

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, fileinputstream

I am having an image stored at a location say : C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SharedCrpto1\web\RetrievedFiles\FILE310@ST-testemp\abc.png .Now when i try to show it in my jsp page the image is not getting visible even when the path to image is correct.

This image is to be displayed after my server process the browsed image provided by the client.

I tried :

```
<img src="<%=path%>" alt="No image" />
```

The image in the particular folder is being created by my servlet like this :

```
File filesstore = new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\SharedCrpto1\\web\\RetrievedFiles\\FILE310@ST-testemp\\");
if(!filesstore.exists())
     {
           System.out.println("MAKING DIRECTORY..");
           filesstore.mkdirs();

     }

To copy one file to this location I did : 

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\test.png");
int xx=fis.available();
byte[] b = new byte[xx];
fis.read(b);
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\SharedCrpto1\\web\\RetrievedFiles\\FILE310@ST-testemp\\abc.png");
fos.write(b);
```

Am i doing something wrong?Please help

Comment: What `path` are you giving? Do you understand the difference between server side and client side processing?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This image is to be displayed after my server process the browsed image provided by the client.

Comment: What is the value of `path`? If you open your browser's network console, what does HTTP request for the image look like?

Comment: is this file and path on the server?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Its something like suppose i have page A.jsp where i have option to browse a file which here i took it C:\\test.png.Then on click of submit suppose second jsp page opens where the image is to be shown at address C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SharedCrpto1\web\RetrievedFiles\FILE310@ST-testemp\abc.png.

Comment: @user3704229 : Have to tried to `print path` in your `console` ? What's it value ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yeah ,they are stored in web folder of my java web application

Comment: Your web server is one machine that contains a path `C://...`. Your browser is on a different machine. What do you expect to happen? And why do you expect that? You should read how HTTP works.

Comment: @user3145373ツ The path is shown correct.Even when i restart my server(apache in my case).The same image may get shown

Comment: `C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\SharedCrpto1\\web\\RetrievedFiles\\FILE310@ST-testemp\\abc.png` is part of you web folder?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The browser is also on same machine.I am just making a servlet program.They both are on same machine

Comment: They don't have to be though. Your client still makes a network call. You should look into how browsers handle `img` elements.

Comment: @ScaryWombat yeah , It is part of my web folder with project name SharedCrpto1 and in web another folder named RetrievedFiles

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The image do get shown when i restart my server or sometime my browser.What can be reason for it?As image is shown it means path is undoubtdly correct

Comment: It is coincidentally correct. The `img` `src` element should be a URL that is accessible through HTTP.

Comment: @ScaryWombat The image do get shown when i restart my server or sometime my browser.What can be reason for it?As image is shown it means path is undoubtdly correct.Is my way of making file and copying it correct?Can their be some buffer or something like this problem?

Comment: All you have to do now is check your browser's network console for the request sent to retrieve that image. Check and get back to us with the details.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What you mean by "accessible through HTTP"?Is the path like <img src="RetrievedFiles/FILE310@ST-testemp/abc.png" /> incorrect?

Comment: why don't you try typing in `http://yoursite/yourApp/RetrievedFiles\FILE310@ST-testemp\abc.png` and see if you can get the image

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What you mean by network console ?

Comment: Every browser has a console that details every HTTP request sent. Check how to open it for whichever browser you are using and use it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat could you please tell more in case of example ? is this what you are saying ? HTTP://C:/Users/admin/Desktop/RetrievedFiles/FILE310@ST-testemp/abc.png"

Comment: no I am suggesting that you test it out with `http://`not `File://`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Please write example solution How to define the path .To make it more understandable please.Taking path to be C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SharedCrpto1\web\RetrievedFiles\FILE310@ST-testemp\abc.png

Comment: @user3704229 - you web application is going to service this resource up to the client in a similar way that it serves up html pages or css etc.

Comment: @ScaryWombat If such is the case then why it display it later on on restarting my server or browser?

Comment: OK how about `http://localhost/SharedCrpto1/RetrievedFiles/FILE310@ST-testemp/abc.pn‌​g`

Comment: Read this: http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/image-element.htm

Comment: @ScaryWombat Dont you think you missed web folder?

Comment: @ScaryWombat No its not working also

Comment: give me a hint, what directory is your html/jsp in?  How do you browse to the html/jsp.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I am using apache Tomcat as server and running my jsps through netbeans IDE for java and directory structure has been posted as image.Please check : http://postimg.org/image/y9ao4jhuj/

Comment: if you call localhost/myApp/index.html and index.html is in the `web` directory and it is wanting a file in `web/images` directory then you will need to call `localhost/myApp/images/a.png` - thats all folks

Comment: @ScaryWombat why not mention web folder ?

Answer (score 0):

From your question what I understood is that You want to read a image file from your local file system & display in a jsp page using

**STEP 1**
For this you need a servlet or jsp which will read the file and convert to byte[] and again write the byte[] to ServletOutputStream .

**STEP 2:**
Create a JSP page which have a img tag & it's src should point to servlet url instead of real file path.As img tag's src attribute can take file path or byte stream.In this we are giving it byte stream because file path will not work.

When you call your jsp page it will try to render the img tag and at that time it will call your servlet & get the byte stream of image data .So it will render your image

Image Servlet

```
@WebServlet("/ImageServlet")
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)                        throws ServletException, IOException {
    //place your file path
    File imageFile =new File("/home/ashok/Pictures/Siberischer.jpg");
    ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    byte[] imageBytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(imageFile);
    outputStream.write(imageBytes);
    outputStream.close();
  }
 }
```

JSP PAGE(to display image) In your jsp just write this tag

**JspPage is the application name & ImageServlet is the servlet url pattern**

```
<img alt="NO IMAGE" src="/JspImage/ImageServlet">
```

> [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi) is present Apache Commons IO Library download the jar to your project